Existence of multidimensional Gaussian processes
Given a positive semi-definite symmetric function $(\Gamma(s,t))_{s,t\in [0,1]}$ there exists a probability space and a centered Gaussian process $X$ with $\mathbb E[X_s X_t] = \Gamma(s,t)$.
Is there a similarly simple characterization for case the where $X$ is Gaussian with values in $\mathbb R^d$, e.g. using cross-covariance?
I can't seem to find anything in that direction other than applying Daniell-Kolmogorov directly, but I'm trying to discuss existence for a whole class of processes with correlated components so it would be nice to have something more convenient.

If I am not mistaken, $(X_t){t \in [0,1]}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued Gaussian process if and only if $(X_t^i){t \in [0,1], i = 1,\dots ,d}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued Gaussian process (where $X_t = (X^1_t, \dots, X^d_t)$). So any positive-definite symmetric $\Gamma : ([0,1] \times { 1,\dots, d})^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ corresponds to a centered Gaussian process on the same space.

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and a set $T$, a (one-dimensional) Gaussian field is a function $f: \Omega \times T \to \mathbb R$, such that $(f_{t_1},\dots, f_{t_n})$ is multivariate Gaussian for all $t_1,\dots, t_n \in T$. A $d$-dimensional Gaussian field is a function $f: \Omega \times T \to \mathbb R^d$, such that the inner product $\langle x, f\rangle$ is a one-dimensional Gaussian field for all $x\in \mathbb R^d$.
Now, I claim that Gaussian fields $f : \Omega \times T\to \mathbb R^d$ and $\tilde f : \Omega \times T\times \{1,\dots, d\} \to \mathbb R, (\omega, t, i)\mapsto f^i_t(\omega)$ are the same.
Proof: Note that $f$ is a Gaussian field if and only if for all $x\in \mathbb R^d, y\in \mathbb R^n$ and $t_1,\dots, t_n\in T$, the following sum is Gaussian
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^d f_{t_j}^k x_k y_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^d \tilde f_{(t_j,k)} x_k y_j \quad (1)$$
Further, $\tilde f$ is Gaussian if and only if for all $t_1,\dots, t_n\in T$ and $i_1,\dots, i_n \in \{1,\dots, d\}$ the following sum is Gaussian
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \tilde f_{(t_j,i_j)} y_j = \sum_{j=1}^n f_{t_j}^{i_j} y_j \quad(2)$$
To get from (1) to (2) write
$$\sum_{j=1}^n f_{t_j}^{i_j} y_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n f_{t_j}^k \delta_{i_j, k} y_j.$$
Conversely, assume $\tilde f$ is Gaussian and that we are given $x,y$ and $t_1,\dots, t_n$. Pick a bijection $\phi : \{1,\dots, n\}\times \{1,\dots, d\} \to \{1,\dots, nd\}$ and define $z\in \mathbb R^{nd}$ as well as $(s_1,i_1),\dots (s_{nd}, i_{nd}) \in T\times \{1,\dots, d\}$ by
$$z_l = x_j y_k, \quad (s_l, i_l) = (t_j, k),\quad l = \phi(j,k), l\leq nd$$
Then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^d \tilde f_{(t_j,k)} x_k y_j = \sum_{l=1}^{nd} \tilde f_{(s_l,i_l)} z_l$$
which is an instance of (2). Thus, the claim is proven. $\square$
Next, the following is well-known (see e.g. the answer by Thomas): for every set $T$ and functions $m : T\to \mathbb R, k : T\times T \to \mathbb R$ where $k$ is positive (semi-) definite there exists a Gaussian field $f : \Omega\times T \to \mathbb R^d$ with mean function $m$ and covariance function $k$. Thus, by replacing $T$ with $T\times \{1,\dots, d\}$ we finally deduce the desired result:
Let $T$ be a set, $d\in \mathbb N$ and $m : T\to \mathbb R^d, k : (T\times \{1,\dots, d\})^2 \to \mathbb R^d$ be functions, such that $k$ is positive (semi-) definite in the sense that for all $n \in \mathbb N, x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $(t_1,i_1),\dots (t_n, i_n) \in T\times \{1,\dots, d\}$ we have
$$\sum_{j,k}^n k(t_j,i_j, t_k, i_k) x_j x_k \geq 0.$$
Then there exists a Gaussian field $f : \Omega \times T \to \mathbb R^d$ with $\mathbb E f_t = m_t, t\in T$ and
$$\mathbb E[X_s^i X_t^j] = k(s,i,t,j), \quad s,t\in T, i,j\in \{1,\dots, d\}.$$

Yes, see Theorem 3.1 in "Remarks on multivariate Gaussian Process"


Unfortunately, the condition on the covariance is too restrictive for my purposes. I need to consider a more general function $k : (T \times {1,\dots,d})^2 \to \mathbb R$ satisfying some positive semidefinite condition.

@StefanPerko Can you explain a bit more? I want to try to modify their proof to include what you need.

Actually, now that I read the statement again it may already be enough, since the index set $T$ is arbitrary, so we could set $T = [0,1]\times {1,\dots, d}$ (my $d$), $d = 1$ (their $d$), $\Lambda = \operatorname{id}$ following the comment by Julius. It remains to show that Gaussian processes $[0,1] \to \mathbb R^d$ and $[0,1]\times {1,\dots, d} \to \mathbb R$ are the same. - oh, and  I translated "covariance function" to "positive (semi-) definite function".
